# MVC .NET Core Dependency injection and base class

Tags: inheritance, .net-core, dependency-injection, radix

I have around 25 classes which implement different rules but all classes need some basic dependency like configuration. I decided to implement base class and derived all these classes from base. I am passing dependency through constructor in base class.

Now the issue is, I am getting error to pass dependency through derived class constructor. if I have to pass dependency in all 25 classes then there is no meaning of using base class. Is there any way base class can sort out dependency by itself instead of passing from outside when instantiate derived class and I can use variable in derived class.

I am using built it Microsoft dependency injection. No DI container are used.

```
 public class Base
  {
    internal IConfiguration _config;
    public Base(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;

    }

 }

 public class derived: Base
 {           
    bool IDisplay.IsMatch(string rule)
    {
        return _config["ApplicationSettings:" + rule].Equals("true");
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: You are going to need to rethink the current design.

Comment: in what sense ? can you give me clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your startup.cs It looks like there is something wrong while adding services